# multiples sequence using range

Tags: python

This is basic again and I've searched throughout the website but I can't find anything that is specifically about this.

The problem is to write a function that takes an integer and returns a certain number of   multiples for that integer. Then, return a list containing those multiples. For example, if you were to input 2 as your number parameter and 4 as your multiples parameter, your function should return a list containing 2, 4, 6, and 8.

What I have so far:

```
def multipleList(number, multiples):
  mult = range(number, multiples, number)
  print mult
```

A test case would be:

```
print multipleList(2, 9):
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

My answer I get:

```
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8]
None
```

I know that range has the format (start, stop, step). But how do you tell it to stop after a certain number of times instead of at a certain number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `(number*multiples)+1` as end value in `range`:

```
>>> def multipleList(number, multiples):
      mult = range(number, (number*multiples)+1 , number)
      return mult
...     
>>> print multipleList(2,9)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> print multipleList(3, 7)
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

The default return value of a function is `None`, as you're not returning anything in your function  so it is going to return `None`. Instead of printing `mult` you should return it.

```
>>> def f():pass
>>> print f()      
None            #default return value
```

Answer (score 2):

try `range(number, number*multiples+1, number)` instead:

```
def multipleList(number, multiples):
    return list(range(number, number*multiples+1, number))

print(multipleList(2, 9))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: It still prints "none" at the bottom. Is there a way to take that off?

Comment: That's because your function returns `None`. See my example

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the following one

```
def mult_list(number, limit):
    multiples = []
    for i in xrange(1, limit+1):
        multiples.append( number * i)
    return multiples
```

For example:
    In [8]: mult_list(2,4)
    Out[8]: [2, 4, 6, 8]

In addition if I do not want parameters an empty list seems consistent with the regular data type:

```
In [10]: mult_list(2,0)
Out[10]: []
```